# NPM cluster module and listening on different ports

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I see a lot of examples of using the cluster npm module with Express web servers. For example:

http://rowanmanning.com/posts/node-cluster-and-express/

However, if you create a new web server 'for each core' using the cluster module, doesn't each instance have to listen on a different port? Most of the examples I see don't seem to increment or change the ports that http servers are listening on. Do you need a proxy server to route requests in this case or can you do without?

Furthermore, when using cluster with its default configuration all nodes listening on the same port, when I make a request to my server, all the the processes (for each core) respond. Seems strange, I would have thought the cluster module would manage that so that only one core would respond to each request.

Comment: _"The cluster module allows you to easily create child processes **that all share server ports**"_ ([here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster), and also [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works)).

Comment: yes but why @robertklep

Comment: Helpful question and answers! Thanks, all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you dont need a proxy or to increment the port for forked process.

When you use the cluster module. There is a master process who controls forked process. This is the master process who dispatch requests over the other child process. So there is no port conflict, the master process handle that.

From the node.js documentation :

"The cluster module supports two methods of distributing incoming connections.

The first one (and the default one on all platforms except Windows), is the round-robin approach, where the master process listens on a port, accepts new connections and distributes them across the workers in a round-robin fashion, with some built-in smarts to avoid overloading a worker process."

you can read this here : https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works

Comment: Answer not matching the question. When a port is been shared, its hard to track each thread.